# Why does my newly rewired light stay on all the time?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, switch

I've installed new hallway and bedroom lights. The hallway light is wired to a 3-way switch & working fine. But now the bedroom (wired to a regular switch) light is on all the time and the switch is not working the light the light just stays on.  I've crossed wires somewhere.

In the bedroom ceiling the junction box has old wires. It looks like 3 black and 1 white. Only one of the blacks are hot.

The new wires coming in are a 3-wire cable (red, black, white). When I test  are all hot.  From what I remember, all the old black wire except 1 were in a wire nut with the red wire and when I took the old light down I'm pretty sure it was just with the black and white from the new 3-wire cable in the box.

Comment: I've removed your contact information. This site is designed to get answers connected to the question for education of future visitors. A private answer defeats this purpose.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved please?

Comment: I've attempted to fix the grammar & spelling issues that I believe were induced by autocowreck. In the future _please_ take a moment to proof read before posting to help others help you. You may want to read through to ensure that I actually got it correct as it was a bit of a mess...

Comment: Did you hook the new light to the same 2 wires the old light was attached to?  Or did you take a bunch of unrelated wires apart?